# Check if object is null before calling method. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, variables, object, reference, initialization

I keep getting a NullReferenceException.  How do I initialize my doubles to determine if they are null?  Sorry for the noob question :(

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{

    //gets new value of slider
    double newValue = (double)Math.Round(e.NewValue);

    //gets current/previous value of slider
    double  currentValue = slider1.Value;

    //gets sum of previous value - new value 
    double valueSum = (double)Math.Round(currentValue - newValue);
```

Comment: Bonus Question:  How do I save the previous value of the slider before it has been dragged to a new value?  I have tried to use GetValue but it has not worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your Bonus question:

The previous value of the slider is provided by the `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<T>` and it is stored in the property `OldValue`.

To answer your question:

The only place in your code that can throw a `NullReferenceException` is when `slider1` is not initialized and is `null`. I assume that the method `slider1_ValueChanged` is called by the UI, so that parameter `sender` and `e` are initialized. So try to attach a debugger an see where the Exception is thrown.